# Why ansible silently ignores a role?

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I have a playbook that requires few roles to run first but for some reason ansible is persistently ignoring one of the roles without any output.

Example playbook:

```
---
- hosts: mirrors
  roles:
    - timezone
    - console
    - core
    - nginx-reverse-proxy
```

Role `nginx-reverse-proxy` requires `nginx` role, so file `roles/nginx-reverse-proxy/meta/main.yml` contains:

```
---
# Dependencies required for nginx-reverse-proxy role

dependencies:
  - nginx
```

When I run the playbook like this: `ansible-playbook -i mirrors/hosts.yml mirrors/playbook.yml`, ansible reaches `nginx-reverse-proxy` role and then immediately starts executing tasks from `roles/nginx-reverse-proxy/tasks/main.yml` completely ignoring `nginx` role from `roles/nginx-reverse-proxy/meta/main.yml`.

What I tried:

1. Putting `nginx` role directly to the playbook after `core` and before `nginx-reverse-proxy` - ansible ignored `nginx` role and skipped immediately to `nginx-reverse-proxy`.
2. Putting some gibberish to `roles/nginx/tasks/main.yml` to see what happens, but ansible doesn't even try to execute it. There is no error like it doesn't even try to parse the file.
3. Running `ansible-playbook` with `-vvvv` switch, but it didn't tell me anything useful.
4. The `nginx` role itself has few files inside `roles/nginx/tasks/` directory. All are yml files that are included in `roles/nginx/tasks/main.yml` conditionally like this:

   ```
   ---
   - include: install_nginx_core.yml
     when: not nginx_extras

   - include: install_nginx_extras.yml
     when: nginx_extras

   - include: setup_ssl.yml

   - include: setup_fastcgi.yml
     # This will also install php5-fpm
     when: setup_fastcgi
   ```

   I removed those files to see if this changes anything, but no luck.

I'm not using any additional switches to run the playbook and it was working fine around version 2.0. But now I'm on 2.1.2.0 and I'm stuck.

**[Edit] Including output of `tree roles/nginx`:**

```
roles/nginx
|-- defaults
|   `-- main.yml
|-- meta
|   `-- main.yml
|-- tasks
|   |-- install_nginx_core.yml
|   |-- install_nginx_extras.yml
|   |-- main.yml
|   |-- setup_fastcgi.yml
|   `-- setup_ssl.yml
`-- templates
    |-- fastcgi.j2
    `-- ssl.conf
```

Comment: That you have tried specifying `nginx` directly in the playbook and haven't seen it do anything makes me very suspicious the problem isn't the dependency definition.  Are you sure you're running the same file as you're modifying?  Can you post the output of `tree roles/nginx`?

Comment: Rename the `nginx` role to `nginxabc` (in the `roles` directory and in the playbook), repeat points 1. and 2.

Comment: @XiongChiamiov I've included tree output. The weird thing is that if misspell `nginx` in `dependencies` ansible notices this and complaints that it can not find a role. So it clearly validates existence of the role correctly yet completely ignores it's playbook.

Comment: @techraf I have just tested this role with different playbook and it worked fine, so why renaming it would help with anything?

Comment: I didn't say it would help with anything. I was interested what is the result.

Comment: Try running only nginx role...is it skipped?

Comment: @ady8531 I tried putting only `nginx` role in the playbook and it is also ignored.

Comment: in the main.yml in tasks in nginx role put a task just before the first include, something like "- shell: echo hello" run it and tell us if it's ignored.

Comment: @ady8531 it is ignored

Comment: Is this is still not working for you in the latest (2.2.0.0)?

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar problem with ansible silently ignoring my role. Turned out that I goofed and I had my file at `roles/myrolename/main.yml` instead of the proper `roles/myrolename/tasks/main.yml`

This may not be the issue that OP had, but I hope this saves someone else the time I wasted banging my head on this stupid mistake.